# ошибка при работе с c++ библиотекой в c#

Tags: c#

в c++ функция выглядит так:

```
LONG WINAPI AVerGetDeviceNum(DWORD *pdwDeviceNum)
```

В c# вызываю так:

```
 [DllImport("123.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern long AVerGetDeviceNum(out uint pdwDeviceNum);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            uint dwDeviceNum;      
            long  lRetVal = AVerGetDeviceNum(out dwDeviceNum);
        }
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

> ConsoleApplication2!ConsoleApplication2.Program::AVerGetDeviceNum"
>   разбалансировал стек. Вероятно, это вызвано тем, что управляемая
>   сигнатура PInvoke не совпадает с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой.
>   Убедитесь, что соглашение о вызовах и параметры сигнатуры PInvoke
>   совпадают с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой.

Comment: а откуда `CallingConvention.Cdecl` взялось?

Comment: Готовую заготовку взял

Comment: попробуй на `StdCall` заменить

Comment: WINAPI может соответствовать stdcall

Comment: @MBo, не может, а в принципе соответствует: [`#define WINAPI __stdcall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types)

Comment: Дефайн всегда такой или может меняться?

Comment: спасибо, помогло)оперативно)

Comment: @MBo, конечно может меняться :-) можно даже вручную переопределить :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макрос `WINAPI` [объявлен](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types) в *WinDef.h* следующим образом

```
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

Поэтому в атрибуте `DllImport` нужно параметру `CallingConvention` установить значение [`CallingConvention.StdCall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_CallingConvention_StdCall)